# Django not let me create project in vs code

Tags: python, django

When I try to create a project in vs code for Django it not let me in
I got exception object not find
Django-admin not recognised as the name of the cmdlet, function
I hAve 3.9.1 and django

Comment: what happens when you run this command? python -m django --version

Comment: could you provide a little more detail?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the project name the same as the module name you have installed.

cmdlet is package  https://pypi.org/project/cmdlet/